# How to unpack an OpenVMS tape image?

Tags: tape, openvms

I have a file that seems to have come from a DECUS tape on an [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) system by way of non-VMS systems using FTP which means that VMS specific file attributes have likely been lost on the way. The contents refers to a backup file name but it is not a backup save set.

```
$ backup/list VAXLIB3.TAP/save_set
Listing of save set(s)

%BACKUP-F-NOTSAVESET, SYS$SYSDEVICE:[USER.CWHII]VAXLIB3.TAP;1 is not a BACKUP save set
```

Here is a dump of the first block.

```
$ dump vaxlib3.tap/blocks=(start:1,count:1)

Dump of file SYS$SYSDEVICE:[USER.CWHII]VAXLIB3.TAP;1 on 11-OCT-2014 21:44:33.10
File ID (8524,9,0)   End of file block 26427 / Allocated 26433

Virtual block number 1 (00000001), 512 (0200) bytes

 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202053 55434544 314C4F56 00000050 P...VOL1DECUS                    000000
 20202020 20202020 20312020 20202020 20202020 43254420 20202020 20202020          D%C          1          000020
 31524448 00000050 00000050 33202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020                    3P...P...HDR1 000040
 30313030 30313030 30205355 43454420 20202020 204B4342 2E334249 4C584156 VAXLIB3.BCK      DECUS 000100010 000060
 4142534D 56434544 30303030 30302030 30303030 20303333 35382030 30313030 00100 85330 00000 000000DECVMSBA 000080
 38303239 31383046 32524448 00000050 00000050 20202020 20202020 50554B43 CKUP        P...P...HDR2F0819208 0000A0
 20202020 2020204D 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20323931 192                     M        0000C0
 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 30302020 20202020       00                         0000E0
 00000000 00000001 00010001 04000100 00002000 00000000 00000050 20202020     P........ .................. 000100
 00000000 00002000 7AEB9361 00010101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ....................a.�z. ...... 000120
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 4B43422E 3342494C 5841560B .VAXLIB3.BCK.................... 000140
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................................ 000160
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................................ 000180
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................................ 0001A0
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................................ 0001C0
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................................ 0001E0
```

How can I unpack the file?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a backup tapeset manually copied to tape?

```
$ Mount [/over=id] the tape
```

and

```
$ COPY *.* or VAXLIB3.BCK to a disk, then BACKUP/LIST VAXLIB3.BCK/SAVE?
```

Comment: As described, tried: "backup/list VAXLIB3.TAP/save_set" along with the response "BACKUP-F-NOTSAVESET".

Comment: Ok, so you only have this file for now. You do NOT have the actual tape. The file seems to have the tape style metadata inside, as variable length record. See those '0050' those indicate 80 byte records coming up. The .TAP file is appears to be a tape image of sorts containing a .BCK saveset butis not a saveset itself. Check: http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/731final/4506/4506pro_002.html Is the .TAP file Fixed length. Try SET FILE/ATT=RFM=VAR and DUMP/RECORD=COUNT=10. You indeed need a tool to 'unpack' as you say. Jur's LMdriver? http://www.digiater.nl/lddriver.html. Google tape to file?